# Can't Display a value from my rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, models, model-associations, rails-models

I'm new to Ruby on Rails and I started with a scaffold and added another model manually.  I can't seem to get the values from the model I manually generated to display in my index view.

My first model is for Golf Courses names, city, par, and hole_id.  The second model is the amount of holes for each course. For some reason I can't get the hole amount to display Below is my code.
Models

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :holes
end

class Hole < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :course
end
```

Controller

```
class CoursesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_course, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /courses
  # GET /courses.json
  def index
    @courses = Course.all
    @holes = Hole.all
  end

  # GET /courses/1
  # GET /courses/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /courses/new
  def new
    @course = Course.new

  end

  # GET /courses/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /courses
  # POST /courses.json
  def create
    @course = Course.new(course_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @course.save
        format.html { redirect_to @course, notice: 'Course was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @course }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @course.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /courses/1
  # PATCH/PUT /courses/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @course.update(course_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @course, notice: 'Course was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @course }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @course.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /courses/1
  # DELETE /courses/1.json
  def destroy
    @course.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to courses_url, notice: 'Course was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_course
      @course = Course.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def course_params
      params.require(:course).permit(:name, :city, :hole_id)
    end
end
```

View

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<p>
  <strong>Name:</strong>
  <%= @course.name %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>City:</strong>
  <%= @course.city %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Hole:</strong>
  <%= @course.holes %>
</p>

<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_course_path(@course) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', courses_path %>
```

Comment: It looks as if you are calling @courses on your "index" controller method, but trying to get the holes in the "show" view..am I right?

Answer (score 0):

`<%= @course.holes %>` gives you an [ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionProxy.html)

You need to ask for its **[size](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionProxy.html#method-i-size)**, **[length](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionProxy.html#method-i-length)** or its **[count](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionProxy.html#method-i-count)** to get the total amount of holes that belong to `@course` which means you have to say `@course.holes.size`, `@course.holes.length` or `@course.holes.count`. Check the documentation for the differences between these three.